# Python how to get parent class variable from an inherited class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x

I have class which inherited from `FileNotFoundError`:

```
class ConfigFileNotFoundError(FileNotFoundError):
    def __init__(self):
        self.filename = super().filename
        FileNotFoundError.__init__(self)
        self.message = "File is absent: {}".format(self.filename)
```

How do I get the `filename` attribute from the `FileNotFoundError`? Because if I do smth like this:

```
if not os.path.isfile(path_to_file):
    raise ConfigFileNotFoundError
```

`self.filename` is `None`.

Comment: Given that you try to get the `filename` *before* you've called the `super` initialiser (and **why** do you mix `super` and `FileNotFound`?!), what did you expect would happen?

Comment: I was very confused with usage of `super()` keyword, and I misunderstanding how it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your invocation of super is completely wrong, because I think you have a misconception about inheritance.

A subclass *is* also a member of its superclass. You don't ask the superclass for an attribute; since you've inherited from it, you gain all the same attributes.

In Python you *do* need to explicitly call the superclass initialization method:

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__(self)
```

which is usually responsible for setting the values of the shared properties.

However, there is a more fundamental issue with your code. You never pass any filename attribute when you raise the exception, so there is no way either the subclass or the superclass could possibly report it. You probably need to do this:

```
def __init__(self, filename):
    super().__init__(self, filename)
```

and

```
raise ConfigFileNotFoundError(my_filename)
```